# Spring Security protect routes hasRole, hasAuthority do not work with CORS http request

Tags: spring-security, jwt, cors

I'm using `Spring Security JWT` to secure `Angular` login page.
I configure `Spring CORS` filter to accept http CORS request.
I verify the JWT is valid in return and authenticated with correct roles.
The secure routes such as `hasRole`, `hasAuthority` fail on CORS requests, it always return 403 status.

```java
//http config
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
  http.cors().and()
    .csrf().disable()
    .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/list_customers").hasAnyRole("ADMIN","DEV") //FAIL 403 error
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/list_customers").hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN") //FAIL 403 error
    .anyRequest().authenticated()
}

//CORS filter
public class CORSFilter extends GenericFilterBean implements Filter {
    
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) 
            throws IOException, ServletException
            {
        HttpServletResponse httpResp = (HttpServletResponse) response;  
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin",  "*");
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers",  "*");
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",  "true");
        httpResp.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Delete your filter and replace it with**

```
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
        configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
        configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
        configuration.setMaxAge(3600l);
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
```

**Reference**

- Have a loot at `org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter` to see how it picks up `CorsConfigurationSource` bean and configures the cors filter
- As you can see in the chain of filters, `CorsFilter` is earlier in the chain than filters checking if the user is authenticated or if they have right permission. Your 403 is thrown much earlier by the `CorsFilter` as it is not configured correctly

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion Kavithakaran, I tried your suggestion also but the same result. None of the secure route is working. It returns 403. Testing from localhost works fine, but it fails when I deploy to github.

Answer (score 0):

Issue Resolved.
I found out my production role name is different.
I changed the role name from ADMIN to ROLE_ADMIN, then it works fine.